# How to programmatically call a click event on list of labels

Tags: label

I have made a 'list' of fuel weights using labels because I wanted to show the list open on iOS devices. This works fine and I can click on a label item and get the weight (100) and the moment (298.16) value.

What I want to do next and I can't figure out how, is I want to make a click event call and have the weight highlighted and pull the moment out as well into a variable.

How do I do this?

```
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="0.00">0</label>
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="298.16">100</label>
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="591.18">200</label>
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="879.08">300</label>
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="1165.42">400</label>
<label class="fuellist_click fuel_colors" data-fuel_moment="1448.40">500</label>
```

This is my code when I manually click on a fuel weight to get the weight and the moment value:

```
$('.fuelLoad').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            //Left Mouse button pressed
            $(this).val(fuel_weight);
            document.getElementById('idfuelLoadMoment').innerHTML = parseFloat(fuel_moment).toFixed(2);
            break;
        case 2:
            //Middle Mouse button pressed
            break;
        case 3:
            //Right Mouse button pressed
            $(this).val(0);// set value to 0
            return false;
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the click event code, which works now to get the fuel weight and th fuel moment value:

```
function fuelListClick(obj) {
    fuel_weight = $(obj).text();
    fuel_moment = $(obj).data("fuel_moment");
    console.log("fuel_weight:" + fuel_weight);
    console.log("fuel_moment:" + fuel_moment);
}
```

Now, I need to be able to call a click event with a specific fuel weight and have it select that item in the list.